# C y/n function failing to accept user input

Tags: c, input

EDIT: This issue has been solved, thanks everyone for the input!

I am working on a very simple project for my C/C++ class, in which the program simulates a 3-round fight between Neo and Agent Smith using user-input damage values for each round. This part of the code works fine, however at the end of the code, the program asks the user if they enjoyed the fight. The user is supposed to enter "y" or "n" and receive the respective statement, however, regardless of what I input, the program returns the "n" statement. My professor asked me to ask Stack Overflow because he can't seem to find any errors in my syntax at a glance.

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double NEO_DAMAGE;
    int SMITH_DAMAGE;
    float NEO_SKILL=10;
    float SMITH_SKILL=12;
    float NEO_MULTIPLIER=1.5;
    float SMITH_MULTIPLIER=1.7;
    int FIGHT_NUMBER =1;
    while (FIGHT_NUMBER<=3)
{
    printf("Round ");
    printf("%d\n", FIGHT_NUMBER);
    printf("Neo and Smith must FIGHT! \n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("How much damage does Neo deal? (1-10)\n");
    scanf("%lf",&NEO_DAMAGE);
    printf("\n");
    printf("How much damage does Smith deal? (1-10)\n");
    scanf("%d",&SMITH_DAMAGE);
    printf("\n");

    SMITH_DAMAGE=SMITH_DAMAGE+((FIGHT_NUMBER-1)*0.5);
    NEO_SKILL=((NEO_SKILL*NEO_MULTIPLIER)-SMITH_DAMAGE);
    SMITH_SKILL=((SMITH_SKILL*SMITH_MULTIPLIER)-NEO_DAMAGE);
    FIGHT_NUMBER=FIGHT_NUMBER+1;
}
    printf("Neo's final skill: ");
    printf("%.3f\n", NEO_SKILL);
    printf("Smith's final skill: ");
    printf("%.3f\n", SMITH_SKILL);

    char answer;
    printf("\nDid you enjoy the fight? (y or n)\n");
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    if (answer == 'y'){
        printf("Wow! You're easily entertained. \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("I can't blame you :c \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When this is compiled in CodeBlocks using GNU GCC compiler, it returns 
"Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))".

Any insight would be much appreciated. Thank you!

-Maxx

Comment: WHY IS EVERYTHING IN CAPS?

Comment: Does your console disappear because your console app is done running such that you just don't see the output?

Comment: BTW, ALL CAPS VAR NAMES ARE CONSIDERED BAD FORM AS THESE ARE OFTEN USED FOR MACROS AND MAKES YOUR CODE awkward to read.

Comment: Bailey and Michael, I'm a total newb leaving total newb stains all over my code. For some backwards reason (probably because of aforementioned newb status) the caps make it easier for me to distinguish between container names and functions/strings. As I progress in this course, I can imagine this habit will change.

@Michael- No, the console does not automatically disappear. It waits for the user to press any key after outputting the "I can't blame you :c" string.

Comment: Note: C and C++ are VERY different languages.  I sincerely hope that some instructor is not trying to teach both languages in a single course

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%c", &answer);
    if (answer == 'y'){`  what happens if the user enters a capital letter or something other than 'y' or 'n'?  suggest checking for a valid entry before testing for the code logic

Comment: OT:  when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]' always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the attendant undefined behavior

Comment: Hi, welcome to [so] if the answer below solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the right answer.  If that did not solve the problem, however you came up with the solution yourself, please post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scanf()` function removes whitespace automatically before trying to parse conversions other than characters. So you should use `scanf(" %c", &answer);` with added white space, otherwise `scanf()` reads any white space left in the input buffer which means it will ignore any character you enter. Therefore the condition `(answer == 'y')` always will be evaluated as false.

Comment: I can't believe this worked! I could have sworn I had already tried that line with a space before the %c and it did not work. I guess my memory failed me yet again. Thank you very much.